# How to check if I'm sending what I need to send for an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, verification

I am trying to do an AJAX call using JQuery, I actually have the next code:

```
$('#form-check').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.domain.com/user/checkurl/",
            type: "GET",
            data: $(location).attr('pathname').substring(17) + "/" + $('#urlTxt').val(),
            error: function(){
                $('#urlTxt').css('background','#ce2b06');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#urlTxt').css('background','#83aa07');
                $('#form-check').css('display','none');
                $('#form-submit').css('display','block');
                $('#result').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

However when I check with Firebug I don't get any response that I can see, I only see the message being sent and on status it says (200 - ok) but nothing gets sent back, and the Ajax call itself does the "success" clause, except that it doesn't append the data. How can I check this? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Check for a "response" part in the Firebug network request. You can also go to the page with your browser to make sure it's working.

Comment: I already went to the page on using my browser and it's working perfectly, but on the "response" tab from Firebug I don't get anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cross domain request. Browsers by default block responses from cross domain sites. You need to use jsonp as the datatype. Just google the same and you can see how it can be done using the jquery API. Stack overflow has questions around these too.

Under the same origin policy, a web page served from server1.example.com cannot normally connect to or communicate with a server other than server1.example.com. An exception is the HTML element. Taking advantage of the open policy for elements, some pages use them to retrieve Javascript code that operates on dynamically-generated JSON-formatted data from other origins. This usage pattern is known as JSONP.

also I am not sure about the way you are passing parameters to the server.. your data field should ideally resemble a json object like

```
{
id:"123",
type:"student"
}
```

also you would ideally would wanna mention the type of response you are expected to receive so that jquery can process it correctly.

This is done by setting the dataType option

dataType: "json" // can be html, xml etc

Comment: but it should be a request from mydomain.com to mydomain.com just a diferent folder ex: I'm in mydomain.com/hey and the request goes to mydomain.com/user/checkurl/

Comment: then I would suggest to keep it as a relative url i.e url: /user/checkurl

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any other browser which do not have any such tools then you can always use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which shows all the `HTTP` traffic on the system.

Answer (score 0):

is it a cross-domain request?

if it is a cross-domain request, you should try to set the option crossDomain:true

check the jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

[Firebug's](http://getfirebug.com/) `Net` tab and [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) both let you see the full traffic between client and server, including all the headers.

Comment: Firebug shows nothing on the response tab but the call gets sent ok, HTTPFox shows me nothing though =/

Comment: Check your javascrsipt error console, then. if it's a cross-domain request, you'll get an error message there.

Comment: how does this help the answer to the question.. this should be a comment.\